# Reading text file into a matrix honouring line breaks

Tags: r, matrix, vector, dataframe

Given is a text file of format

```
123
456
789
```

I would like to read this file into a matrix **M** resembling:

```
M <- matrix(data = c(1:9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

*which gives:*

```
>> str(M)
 int [1:3, 1:3] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

## Initial attempt

```
impGrid <- readLines(con = "grid.txt")
lapply(X = strsplit(x = impGrid, split = ""), as.data.frame)
```

The *`grid.txt`* corresponds to a file of previously provided characteristics. So far this does not work, an alternative approach would involve working `readLines(con = "grid.txt")` vector converting it to a [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) and breaking down strings of number into columns. At this junction it occurred to me that there must be a neater way of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read.fwf()`:

```
read.fwf("grid.txt", widths = c(1,1,1))

#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  2  3
#2  4  5  6
#3  7  8  9
```